# git print filename and last updated date

Tags: git, last-modified

Is there a git command to show :

```
filename last_updated
```

The closest I came up is :

```
git log --format=format:'%ci' --name-only
```

but this need processing and parsing to get what I want.

Comment: Why you don't like 'ls -lah' ? What date you interesting in - on remote server or local?

Answer (score 0):

thanks xcorsx... you point me to the right direction :

```
find ./ -type f -printf "%h/%f %TY-%Tm-%Td\n"
```

Comment: Just so you know, this will print the date of _all_ files within the current directory, not just those tracked by Git.